# Laravel date validation rule is invalid when use casts and rules

Tags: php, laravel

When `casts` and `rules` of a field in my model are set to date at the same time, and the value of input is an illegal character,
my validation rule date is equivalent to invalid.

```
$input = [            
            "datetime": "asxdasda",
            "original_owner_dod": "zxc"
];
new UserModel($input);
```

When I pass an illegal string to a field with date validation rules, I get `carbon\exceptions\invalidformatexception`.
Unexpected data found.
Trailing data is an exception like this exception.

Why not verify the field first and then do the data conversion?

Comment: same problem. Did you find a solution? The problem is that *validator* is executed *after* the cast, so when user insert an invalid date laravel app crashes before data being validated at all

Answer (score 0):

Because Laravel expects you to supply valid information, if it starts to implement it's own logic (like continuing to run the program), that may lead to unexpected results.

You can verify it yourself tho!

```
if (strtotime($datetime) === false) {
    // The date is not correctly formatted
    // Here you can do something like rewriting the field or making it null
}
```

Comment: I think laravel should verify the data first, not convert it first. In some cases, the data entered by the user may not be legal.

Comment: It is verifying the date, thats why you got the InvalidFormatException, you just didn't catch it and specified what behaviour should follow :P